# VBA find matching Excel files with a subtext - and merge them into single new file

Tags: excel, vba, loops, merge, append

I have excel files with suffixes like this.  Final_38200_1.xls, _2.xls, _3.xls etc.  I also have files with a _0 suffix.

The _0 suffix files are for purposes of this question done.  don't need touched.

For the suffixes greater than 0 - with matching prefix, these files need appended together into a new _0 file.  they are parts of a whole. I need the data all on the same sheet.

There is a rate code column, which I update based on the suffix number currently.  After all the updating - i then need to final_38200_1 final_38200_2 files into a new final_38200_0 file.

here's the code i use to modify rate code based on suffix.

```
[Sub Subshed_Rates()

Dim ss As String
Dim s As String

Dim name As String

Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
name = fso.GetBaseName(ActiveWorkbook.name)

'Debug.Print (name)


s = Right(name, 1)

If s > 0 Then
ss = "S" & s
ElseIf s = 0 Then Exit Sub
End If

Range("E1:E40000").Select

Selection.Replace What:="*AG*", Replacement:=ss & " AG", 
LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, 
SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="*RES*", Replacement:=ss & " RES", 
LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, 
SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="*COM*", Replacement:=ss & " COMM", 
LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, 
SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub]
```

After that - I need to amend _1 and _2 to a new _0 file.
how do i do that?

Comment: It'd help if you showed what code you have so far on this. So if you can loop through the directory, similar to finding the ones above 0, you can validate against the first section and append the like files with the same prefix

Comment: Agree with @MarkS. - Your question is likely to be closed due to lack of a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and debugging details.  If you can add these, ping me and I'll consider voting to reopen (or retracting my close-vote, if it's still open). Thanks!

Comment: Although a little bit old fashioned, instead of using the FileSystemObject, you probably are better of using the `Dir`-command that can be used with wildcards. There are tons of example here on SO and elsewhere. For creating a Workbook/Sheet containing the content of multiple files, there are also a lot of examples.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds  I've edited the post - really not sure how to ask the questions, as what I have right now - is a series of cleanup macros, and now that I have the data cleaned up - I need to merge certain files - that have a subshed number (the suffix greater than 0) into a single file with a suffix of _0 -- but there are more than one instance (different prefix files - that will need this.

Comment: Thanks @Troy - I've voted to reopen the question and put in a request to others for it as well.  However, keep an eye out for comments from others who may request additional information. It's probably still not crystal clear, but IMHO it's close enough that it should be left open (unless closed for duplicate or other reasons).